# Adding object to Arraylist in one frame but then cannot access it in the second already opened frame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

abit of a weird one but i have a frame that contains a search bar so that when the user types a certain drug name it will search an arraylist (allDrugs) that contains all of the drugs and simply show its information in a textArea.

That works fine but if i then go to create another drug which opens a second frame, fill in all the information,save that information as a new drug object and then add it to the allDrugs arrayList, i then go back to the original frame that is still open and try to search the new drug name, it cannot then find this new drug created.

Its almost like i have to refresh the frame but i have tried, removeAll, validate(), repaint() but it still cant find the new drug.
Below is the search bar that is kinda of the main window or frame1.

```
searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == searchButton)
            {
                try
                {
                    for(Drug d: allDrugs)
                    {
                        //finished here, makesure that the string that comes in from the name of the drug from the field is the same as the one already i nthe arraylist
                        //Done by capitalising the first letter no matter what.
                        if(d.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchField.getText()))
                        {
                                MainMenu.textArea.setText(null);
                                MainMenu.textArea.append(d.allDetailsToString());
                                MainMenu.textArea.setEditable(false);
                                break;
                        }

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Drug not found");
                        break;

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error when searching for drug");
                }
            }
```

this is the createDrug method that exists in frame2:

```
 private void createDrug(ArrayList<Drug>allDrugs)
        {  
 String name = nameField.getText().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + nameField.getText().substring(1);
                Drug drug = new Drug(name, classField.getText(), aimArea.getText(), moaArea.getText(), altArea.getText(), dosageArea.getText(), observationArea.getText(), durationArea.getText(), elimArea.getText(), unwantedArea.getText(), interactionArea.getText(), ideasArea.getText());
                allDrugs.add(drug);
```

I apologise if this is abit difficult to follow.
So pretty much how can i make it so when a new drug is created i nframe 2, then the search bar that is still open in frame1 will then pick up the newly added drug?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) (It sounds like the 2nd frame should be a dialog. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank Andrew i solved the problem with LEE's answer but i will reconsider using multiple frames after reading that post you linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried search the any item other than the first item in the drug list? From what I see, your `foreach` loop will break once it find the first item is not the target.

```
for(Drug d: allDrugs)
{
    //finished here, makesure that the string that comes in from the name of the drug from the field is the same as the one already i nthe arraylist
    //Done by capitalising the first letter no matter what.
    if(d.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchField.getText()))
    {
         MainMenu.textArea.setText(null);
         MainMenu.textArea.append(d.allDetailsToString());
         MainMenu.textArea.setEditable(false);
         break;
    }
    //this will run for the first loop round and it will break the loop if the first item in list is not the search target
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Drug not found");
    break;

}
```

Your `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Drug not found");` should be outside of the loop and the `break;` should be thrown.

```
boolean found = false;
for(Drug d: allDrugs)
{
    //finished here, makesure that the string that comes in from the name of the drug from the field is the same as the one already i nthe arraylist
    //Done by capitalising the first letter no matter what.
    if(d.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchField.getText()))
    {
         MainMenu.textArea.setText(null);
         MainMenu.textArea.append(d.allDetailsToString());
         MainMenu.textArea.setEditable(false);
         found = true;
         break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Drug not found");
```

Hope it helps.